# What is the difference between Firebase auth and Auth0 authentication

Tags: firebase-authentication, auth0

How does http://auth0.com's authentication features compare to Firebase's authentication?

Does Auth0.com, on the Free or Silver plan, provide any authentication features that Firebase does not provide?

Answer (score 24):

One major difference between the two (not mentioned in the blog linked in [Jake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9206039/jake-miyazaki)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48799174/1763012)) is **pricing**. Auth0's pricing increases pretty quick along with the number of active users ([source](https://auth0.com/pricing/)) whereas Firebase Auth is free to use; you only pay for optional features like SMS, and database usage in case you need to [store additional user metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44161502/1763012) for more about Firebase Auth pricing.

Comment: Another issue that I face is that Firebase does not work in China.