# Ionic2 authentication: auth0 vs ionic cloud service

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, firebase-authentication, auth0

I need to implement login functionality in an Ionic2 app. Goal is to allow various social login providers as well (Google, FB, Twitter).
I've done this earlier (Ionic1) in a custom way, but now I prefer a framework that handles the calls for me. It seems there is more than one option:

- Ionic (cloud) auth service
- Auth0
- Firebase

It's quite unclear for me how hey exactly differ and which one should be the preferred choice. I can't find existing articles pointing this out (except for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827628/difference-between-firebase-and-auth0-authentication) one). Although I see some of these can even be combined which makes it even more mysterious.

Rather than learning everything about those 3 first to make a fact-based decision, I'd love to hear some experienced opinions. Don't want to start a discussion, just get some facts about features, performance, errorproofness etc.

Comment: I understood that I have to use the Ionic cloud auth service in order to be able to use their Push Notification service. Therefore, I did not event look for any alternatives, because I'm trying to avoid having to handle push notifications to different devices myself. Please correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: @pwagner This is also provided by firebase

Comment: Did you ever reach a conclusion on this? I am deliberating right now between using the Ionic (cloud) auth service and Auth0 for an Ionic3 app. Curious to hear what you came up with. Thanks!

Comment: Yoni, I started with ionic but quickly changed to firebase due to the lack of flexibility and cross platform with ionic. Quite satisfied with the firebase solution now, it integrates nicely with their db as well.