# Which pricing tier mentions Firebase Authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Where can I find info on firebase authentication pricing?  Is there any fee to use it, which tier, is there a threshold?

It's not even mentioned on the pricing page at all

Comment: Don't cross-pos questions please: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/716#issuecomment-303604151

Comment: Im not cross-posting dude :/ I checked the site, nothing, I googled it, nothing.  Nice people like @jen-person were here to assist, why on earth would I even check Git Issues for a simple pricing issue, that alone seems insane and a drain on the dev team.  You need to realize for the "new to firebase" people it's not obvious in the least, its mentioned nowhere.  Phone pricing is there sure, but no mention of users or leveraging the OAuth Firebase API to log in users...

Comment: Apologies for misclassifying your question as a cross-post. We're looking for ways to clarify the auth pricing without further cluttering the pricing page. Let me know if you have any other questions about it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Authentication pricing is not mentioned on the pricing page at all because there isn't a fee to use Firebase Authentication. As a result, there is no threshold for doing that.

Comment: Most of Firebase Authentication is free. Phone number auth has a free tier but is priced after that. Please see about 1/3 down on the pricing page: https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: Could you clarify the following please? My understanding is that Firebase Auth needs to use Cloud Firestore (or Realtime DB) as its datastore, and Firestore has costs. Is that correct? If that's the case, can Firebase Auth really be considered free, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Anthony No, it's not. You can use Firebase authentication regardless of the use of Firebase realtime database or Cloud Firestore. If you want to store particular details of your user, then you can use one of the this solution for storing data but note that are not related.

Comment: So, can I assume that if we are using Firebase Authentication service ( except Phone authentication) everything is free. We will not be charged anything for the storage regardless of the number of users present in Firebase for authentication. The only confusion is since Firebase will be using some kind of storage for storing user details for authentication, would it be charged or storage is part of the authentication package ?

Comment: @DileepSingh As also Frank van Puffelen mentioned in his answer, yes, you can assume that.