# Is it smart to use Google Firebase ONLY for authentication

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I wonder may there be a problem using Firebase **only for authentication** for spring boot- angular app. It is very easy and I am very familiar with it. Or is it dependent on app size? Very appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth), then simply use it. There are no restrictions regarding the size of the app. Besides that, it's [completely free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44161195/which-pricing-tier-mentions-firebase-authentication), unless you are using the phone number authentication, which has a free tier that is priced [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).